# MySQL no retorna datos a JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy tratando de Hacer un consulta a mi `DB` pero no me devuelve nada, ni error, o alguna otra forma de hacerlo

```js
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        coneccion con = new coneccion();
        Connection c = con.conectar();
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        String sql = String.format("select * from administrador where PERSONA_CodiPers='10020000' and ContrAdmi='123456'");
        ResultSet res = s.executeQuery(sql);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "op3");
        //System.out.println(sql);
        int rows = res.getRow();
//            res.last();
//            rows = res.getRow();
//            res.beforeFirst();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.valueOf(rows));

    }
}
```

```html
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class coneccion {

    public Connection conectar = null;

    public Connection conectar() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conectar = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/colegio1", "root", "123456");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return conectar;
    }

    public void desconectar() {
        try {
            conectar.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas seguro que executequery devuelve lo que vos pensas que devuelve?

Answer (score 0):

Quiero pensar que lo que buscas imprimir en el JOption es que esta "activo", lo que tienes que realizar es:

```
res.next();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, res.getString("EstaAdmi"));
```

ya que lo que estas imprimiendo es el numero de Fila donde comienza la lectura.
"res.next();" lo que hace es pasar a la siguiente fila que es donde esta tu resultado, y "res.getString("EstaAdmi");" es el nombre de la columna junto con su tipo de dato que deseas imprimir.

Comment: Por favor no supongas, te recomiendo leer el artículo: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342)

Comment: Malas preguntas normalmente reciben malas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

el problema no es el select si no el metodo que estas utilizando

> res.getRow() : Recupera el número de fila actual. La primera fila es el número 1, el segundo número 2, y así sucesivamente.
>   Nota: el soporte para el método getRow es opcional para ResultSets con un tipo de conjunto de resultados TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY
>   Devoluciones:
>   el número de fila actual; 0 si no hay una fila actual
>   Tiros

Es Decir no devuelve el número de filas afectadas ,podrías utilizar este método para contar las filas.

```
public class test {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    coneccion con = new coneccion();
    Connection c = con.conectar();
    Statement s = c.createStatement();
    String sql = String.format("select * from administrador where PERSONA_CodiPers='10020000' and ContrAdmi='123456'");
    ResultSet res = s.executeQuery(sql);

    int total = 0;
    while (res.next()){
    //Obtienes la data que necesitas...Ejemplo
    System.err.println("EstaAdmi:"+res.getString("EstaAdmi"));
    total++;
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Filas:"+total);

}

}
```